# Creating Pydantic Model Schema with Dynamic Key

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

I'm trying to implement Pydantic Schema Models for the following JSON.

```
{
    "description": "Best Authors And Their Books",
    "authorInfo":
    {
        "KISHAN":
            {
            "numberOfBooks": 10,
            "bestBookIds": [0, 2, 3, 7]
            },
        "BALARAM":
            {
            "numberOfBooks": 15,
            "bestBookIds": [10, 12, 14]
            },
        "RAM":
            {
            "numberOfBooks": 6,
            "bestBookIds": [3,5]

        }
    }
}
```

Here are the schema objects in Pydantic

```
from typing import List, Type, Dict
from pydantic import BaseModel

class AuthorBookDetails(BaseModel):
    numberOfBooks: int
    bestBookIds: List[int]

class AuthorInfoCreate(BaseModel):
    __root__: Dict[str, Type[AuthorBookDetails]]    
#pass

class ScreenCreate(BaseModel):
    description: str
    authorInfo: Type[AuthorInfoCreate]
```

I'm parsing the AuthorInfoCreate as follows:

```
y = AuthorBookDetails( numberOfBooks = 10, bestBookIds = [3,5])
print(y)
print(type(y))

x = AuthorInfoCreate.parse_obj({"RAM" : y})
print(x)
```

I see the following error.

```
numberOfBooks=10 bestBookIds=[3, 5]

<class '__main__.AuthorBookDetails'>

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "test.py", line 44, in <module>

    x = AuthorInfoCreate.parse_obj({"RAM": y})

  File "C:\sources\rep-funds\env\lib\site-packages\pydantic\main.py", line 402, in parse_obj

    return cls(**obj)

  File "C:\sources\rep-funds\env\lib\site-packages\pydantic\main.py", line 283, in __init__

    raise validation_error

pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 1 validation error for AuthorInfoCreate

__root__ -> RAM

  subclass of AuthorBookDetails expected (type=type_error.subclass; expected_class=AuthorBookDetails)
```

I want to understand how can I change AuthorInfoCreate so that I have the json schema mentioned.

Comment: the unhashable type error is due to trying to create a set from a duct, nothing to do with pydantic.

Comment: I changed my question to see what exactly I was looking for. I want to understand how can I change AuthorInfoCreate so that I have the json schema mentioned.

Comment: @navule did you find the solution?

Comment: @SKhalymon not yet. May be I need to try with latest Pydantic documentation for and clue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Actually you should remove Type from type annotations. You need an instance of a class, not an actual class. Try the solution below:

```py
from typing import List,Dict
from pydantic import BaseModel

class AuthorBookDetails(BaseModel):
    numberOfBooks: int
    bestBookIds: List[int]

class AuthorInfoCreate(BaseModel):
    __root__: Dict[str, AuthorBookDetails]

class ScreenCreate(BaseModel):
    description: str
    authorInfo: AuthorInfoCreate
```

Comment: What If I want multiple dynamic key one using AuthorBookDetails as base model and once lets say AuthorDetails. 
I don't think we can bind both models to __root__, what would you do In that scenario

Comment: @Callmeashish I don't know how to do it with Pydantic, but you could check https://trafaret.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro.html which allows doing much more than Pydantic in terms of validation.

Answer (score 4):

For those with how to Initialize Pydantic classes, with the answer given by @SKhalymon,

```py
from typing import List, Dict
from pydantic import BaseModel

class AuthorBookDetails(BaseModel):
    numberOfBooks: int
    bestBookIds: List[int]

class AuthorInfoCreate(BaseModel):
    __root__: Dict[str, AuthorBookDetails]

class ScreenCreate(BaseModel):
    description: str
    authorInfo: AuthorInfoCreate



kishan = AuthorBookDetails( numberOfBooks = 10, bestBookIds = [0, 2, 3, 7])

balram = AuthorBookDetails( numberOfBooks = 15, bestBookIds = [10, 12, 14])

ram = AuthorBookDetails( numberOfBooks = 6, bestBookIds = [3, 5])

aic = AuthorInfoCreate(__root__={"KISHAN": kishan, "BALRAM": balram, "RAM": ram})

sc = ScreenCreate( description = "Best Authors And Their Books", authorInfo = aic)

print(sc.json())
```

Output:

```
{"description": "Best Authors And Their Books", "authorInfo": {"__root__": {"KISHAN": {"numberOfBooks": 10, "bestBookIds": [0, 2, 3, 7]}, "BALRAM": {"numberOfBooks": 15, "bestBookIds": [10, 12, 14]}, "RAM": {"numberOfBooks": 6, "bestBookIds": [3, 5]}}}}
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to do this with pydantic Version >= 2.0.0 the code would look like this:

```
from typing import List, Dict, Union
from pydantic import BaseModel, RootModel

class AuthorBookDetails(BaseModel):
    numberOfBooks: int
    bestBookIds: List[int]

class AuthorInfoCreate(RootModel[Dict[str, Dict]]):
    root: Dict[str, AuthorBookDetails]

class ScreenCreate(BaseModel):
    description: str
    authorInfo: AuthorInfoCreate
```

Answer (score 0):

From [pydantic issue #2100](https://github.com/samuelcolvin/pydantic/issues/2100#issuecomment-723678345)

> `__root__` is only supported at parent level.

That's why it's not possible to use

```
class AuthorInfoCreate(BaseModel):
    __root__: Dict[str, AuthorBookDetails]
```

The following workaround is proposed in the above mentioned issue

> ```
> from typing import Any, Dict, List
>
> from pydantic import BaseModel as PydanticBaseModel
> from pydantic.utils import ROOT_KEY
>
>
> class BaseModel(PydanticBaseModel):
>     def __init__(__pydantic_self__, **data: Any) -> None:
>         if __pydantic_self__.__custom_root_type__ and data.keys() != {ROOT_KEY}:
>             data = {ROOT_KEY: data}
>         super().__init__(**data)
>
> ...
> ...
> ```

Now it's possible to use `AuthorInfoCreate` model in the usual way

```
aic = AuthorInfoCreate(**{"KISHAN": kishan, "BALRAM": balram, "RAM": ram})
```

[PR #2237](https://github.com/samuelcolvin/pydantic/pull/2237) should make the workaround above unnecessary.